# How to use CellEndEdit event in datagridview using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, datagridview

In the data grid,I have two columns A and B.

I need only one column to be filled in a row.

In this,after filling column A,if i try to fill column B or vice-verse, I need the other column to be empty.

Note: I am filling the grid manually.

Please help me out of this and thanks in advance.

Comment: What i exactly wanted was,I need to clear the column A once i start writing in column B and vice-verse. Please give a idea to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DataGridViewCellEventArgs parameter you get from that event tells you which column and row you are currently editing, so you can easily wipe out the other column with that information:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) _
                                              Handles dgv.CellEndEdit
  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = String.Empty
  ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = String.Empty
  End If
End Sub
```

To do this when the user *starts* to edit the cell, simply use the CellBeginEdit event instead:

```
Private Sub dgv_CellBeginEdit(sender As Object, _
                              e As DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs) _
                              Handles dgv.CellBeginEdit
  If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Value = String.Empty
  ElseIf e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
    dgv.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Value = String.Empty
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this. It works but not like exactly what i need.            I need to clear the column A once i start writing in column B and vice-verse. Please give a idea to solve

Comment: @Malar Updated post.  Just use the `CellBeginEdit` event instead.